# What's proper way to copy DLLs to $(OutDir) in Visual studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

What's the correct way to add DDLs to Visual studio C++ project so that the DLL would be copied to (OutDir)? My goal is to make sure that the DLL in OutDir is always identical to the source DLL, e.g. even if for some reason DLL is OutDir gets newer timestamp during build it would be updated to ensure that it's identical to what's included in the project?

**EDIT**: 
There are obvious solutions like using prebuild/postbuild events to to manually copy dll to where you want to. This is kind of ok for basic home project but this isn't acceptable in real projects for a few reasons. For example, there is no dependency tracking of the DLL itself. If somebody commits just the dll then there won't be any build needed and prebuild/postbuild event will be skipped. This totally breaks CI and auto tests as the update dll won't be copied until something is committed that triggers recompilation.
So far I haven't found anything that works properly, which is just surprising. The only thing that remotely resembles properly functioning implementation is the [MSBuild's Copy Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) but this doesn't have integration with VS IDE and if you use it you magically have these dlls copied without even knowing why and where they are referenced from. We also tried to implement PublishDLLDependency rule for .dll but that doesn't work well, as this will follow make-style dependency checks and won't copy dlls if you haven to have newer dlls in OutDir. CopyTask uses correct approach for this scenario: just like robocopy it compares size and timestamp when copying.
In short, there should be proper mechanism build-in into IDE that allows you to add some DLLs and have them copied to OutDir when project that depends on these is build. When properly implemented, if I do F7 (Build) I should see something like this:

```
Copying some.dll
Copying other.dll
...
Compiling a.cpp
...
```

and when F7 is hit, it should test if these dlls need to be copied just like it checks all the steps if anything needs to be compiled/linked. This dll copy step shouldn't be tied to any build event, it has to be unrelated to rebuild, relink or any other event, as the dll (in my case) isn't build but the project and comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Could you get useful information from answer? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with copy task in the Post-Build Event. Visual Studio allows you to define events to occur, before, or after building. Right-click on your C++ project in the solution explorer window and select 'properties'. In the left hand side select the 'Build Events' tab and select “Post-Build Event”, edit below command:

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)SourceDLLFolder\Test.dll" "$(OutDir)" /y /s
```

Where $( ProjectDir) and $( OutDir) are both predefined variables.

[image]

Comment: This is completely non-proper way to do it.

Comment: Are you from MSFT? I'll explain why it's not acceptable/non-proper way in my question.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I may not be able to understand your problem accurately, The detailed explanation will be of great help in solving this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I added explanation of what's unacceptable with xcopy. In my case we had xcopy failed occasionally also and ended up with 0-sized copies that were newer than source dll and that would break servers. I do use xcopy with /v to verify that it was copied. Somehow in high load build farm it breaks quite often, as this seemingly common scenario isn't properly supported by VS itself.